# Method returning a NullPointerException when it should be returning a -1

Tags: java, arrays

The following code works perfectly fine as long as the name I input is in the directory. If the name doesn't exist in the directory, it returns a NullPointerException. I don't understand cos if the name doesn't exist in the directory, it should just return the -1. Why the exception? Thanks for any guidance.

```
public  class  Direct{
    //Directory is a class that contain a name and get/set methods for it.
    private Directory[] directory = new Directory[100];

        public int find(String name){
            for (int x=0; x < directory.length; x++){
                if (directory[x].getName().equals(name)){ //exception refers to this line to hold the error
                    return x;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        }
}



//Testing on main method

Direct direct = new Direct();

//This works cos the name John is in the directory.
System.out.println(direct.find("John"));

This returns an error cos x is not present in the directory.
System.out.println(direct.find("x"));
```

Comment: have you initialized `directory array` with some Directory object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a `Directory` array of length `100`, it starts out with 100 `null` references.  You reached past all existing `Directory` objects that are filled in (if any), and you have reached a `null` reference before reaching the end of the array.

Test for `directory[x]` being `null` before accessing `getName()`.  It's up to you whether to immediately return `-1` on a `null` array element or to continue searching the array.

Comment: Thanks it works. My (wrong)understanding was that if the name is not = null, it should keep looping till the end.

Answer (score 0):

`directory[x].getName()` is null. First check if it is null or not and then do the `.getName()`